# Partition the disk Without rebooting

Tags: partitioning, reboot, lvm

How to extend the partition table Without rebooting? The change should be informed to kernel without rebooting.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to set up your system using [LVM](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm) to get the flexibility of manipulating partitions on the fly.  You can even pick up and move your system partition from one disk to another using LVM.  For normal partition tables, `gparted` can add new partitions without rebooting, and delete/move/resize existing partitions as long as they are not currently mounted.  With msdos partition tables, if one logical partition is mounted then the whole extended partition is considered mounted so you can't resize it.  This restriction is lifted in 14.04, as well as gaining the ability to grow mounted partitions ( for most filesystem types ).

Comment: Psusi thanks i can expand my locigal volume,But what my problem is after expanding the size i want to reboot my system i am not interested to do that

Comment: @Premkumar, that didn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

if you use Ubuntu 12.xx+ search unity with "Disks" then click that icon.you will see the partitions.if you use single partition of all entire hard disc,backup your datas and part your hard disk without rebooting or formatting

Comment: Umm... no... you can't manipulate your system partition while using it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you cannot do it while using .Only way is that: install Remastersys and backup all your data (including home folder) and save that iso image(nearly 2 GB) to external memory.then you can manipulate you hard disc with ubuntu live  cd and reinstall backed up remastersys iso image.thats clear way

Comment: Oh thanks is there any other way to do that in command line without righting it into the live cd